# Good practice for local def in a complex method

Tags: scala, readability

I am about to write a quite long treatment which I expect to exceed 130 lines. In Java, I would have written a public method and several private methods to split the logic into more readable pieces of code.

However, those private methods would not be useful to any other method in this class, then I would like to make them local to my public method since Scala enables this. Yet, in that case the method is even longer than without local defs and since I don't need to call these local functions several times, it seems useless.

To sum up, I have to choose between

```
def method {
    def localDef1 = { 
        // 20-30 lines of code
    }
    def localDef2 = { 
        // 20-30 lines of code
    }
    def localDef3 = { 
        // 20-30 lines of code
    }
    // 30-40 lines of code calling localDef[1-3] once each
}
```

and

```
def method {   
    // 30-40 lines of code calling privateDef[1-3] once each
}
private def privateDef1 = { 
    // 20-30 lines of code
}    
private def privateDef2 = { 
    // 20-30 lines of code
}
private def privateDef3 = { 
    // 20-30 lines of code
}
```

What would be the best practice in terms of readability for something like this ?

Comment: This very much depends on personal coding style preferences. If things get too big, I have a tendency to use `private def`s instead of local `def`s, but others might disagree.

Comment: @sjrd Fine, I wanted to know if there had an implicit and generally admitted convention for that. Thanks for your answer

Comment: Since these methods are so long, I'm guessing you'll want to write tests for them - so you'd have to go with option 2.

Comment: @ChrisMartin Fair point !

Comment: Are these methods or pure functions; meaning that do they also return a value ? If yes, then you can keep them public and write tests for them easily.

Comment: Maintain the locality of reference. If these methods won't be used outside the big method, you can keep them nested inside big method.

Comment: That's what I wanted to do, but it is not really more readable that not using separate methods at all, and have just a huge chunk of code in a single method.

Comment: I would say it's almost always possible to have fine-grained focused functions. Then the only challenge is to put them in the right place which depends on what they are doing, whether they need a dependency, they hold state or not, etc. But the good thing is in Scala with help of `implicit` parameters you can simplify the common parts by implicitly bringing stuff to your current context. Companion objects are also a good place to put common code. Generalising by control abstraction is also an encouraged way of achieving reusability in FP and Scala.

Comment: Even if the code is not used anywhere else putting the common functionality in fine-grained `trait`s makes sense. You can use [package-private accessors](http://www.scala-lang.org/old/node/10488) or a [package object](http://www.scala-lang.org/docu/files/packageobjects/packageobjects.html) to hide this details while keeping the option to mix them in as traits. This way you can easily aggregate them while hiding them from outside world. One more advantage of this approach is easier unit testing.

Comment: Thanks for your advices, I think it would make a fine answer if you compiled your comments

Comment: Maybe you can elaborate a bit more, suggesting a concrete approach with just knowing a general abstract idea is difficult and could be irrelative of what you really want to achieve.

Comment: @NaderHadjiGhanbari You are right, but it would become a Code Review question. I'm currently implementing the method with private methods, I'll see what to do for the question when it will be over

Comment: @Dici Sounds fair, will be glad to help.